# Pageable in controller not instantiated

Tags: spring, testing

I have a spring-boot app with controller that uses Pageable as an argument to one of its methods. It works fine. But I want to use spring-contract-verifier to generate and execute tests.
Base class for tests looks like this:

```
public class MvcTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(new Controller());
    }
}
```

The exception I'm getting is:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable]: Specified class is an interface
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:99)
```

I searched SO and I found out that I should add

```
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
```

to my configuration class. I created a class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class WebConfig {
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to tell contract verifier to pull this class into configuration.
Thanks

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I'm pretty sure you didn't mean to import `java.awt.print.Pageable`.

Comment: Corrected, but problem still persists.

Answer (score 5):

Its the wrong pagable: use [`org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) instead of `java.awt.print.Pageable`.

you need to enable

```
 @EnableSpringDataWebSupport
```

or

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration" />
```

@see: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web

Comment: *[deleted my original comment as after the edit the answer no longer looks like a wild guess ;)]*

Comment: As per my initial post - @EnableSpringDataWebSupport is already there.